# How do i solve "make matcaffe" error on ubuntu?

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04, mex, caffe, matcaffe

I'm working on window10 64-bit and VirtualBox ubuntu-14.04 I'd like to work with matlab and caffe. When I try to run `make matcaffe` the following error appears:

> make: /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/mexext: Command not found MEX matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.cpp /bin/sh: 1:
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/mex: not found make: *** [matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.] Error 127

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: MEX is a command internal to MATLAB. Trying to invoke MEX in the Terminal will give you that error because you're not running MATLAB.

Comment: Please give me more detail.